# Which is the best place where to consume kafka topic in Google cloud platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, serverless, google-cloud-run

we have a microservices architecture developed on Google cloud.
Actually the microservices are all running on cloud run and talk each other with rest (sync) or with pub/sub (async).

It is an event-driven pattern so when a service publish something happened (like "user_created") on the right pub/sub topic, many services receive that event with a **push** subscription on their http endpoint.

Now we are moving to kafka for message ordering and replaying features.
Unfortunately kafka consumers are pull based so we need to change the way services are receiving events.

Since cloud run is a serverless solutions that scale to zero, we cannot make it listen to kafka topic, because the service could shut down during the night because no request arrive.

We have different services which can safely be updated with a scheduled cron, so every one hour as example, we make a get request to service, which download all new kafka messages and update itself accordingly.

But many other services need a near real time update to accomplish their role.

So which product of google cloud platform is best suited to consume kafka topic in this architecture?

Thanks!

Comment: Before switching, have you see this new [PubSub feature](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering)? If it's enough for you, what is the challenge with the message replay that leads you to switch to Kafka?

Comment: I love PubSub and i will continue to use it in many use-cases and in many other projects where it fits perfectly. I just like the idea of the kafka stream api where i can convert events coming from a service before processing them and then fill other service with specific connector. I'm just trying to learn this technology (kafka) but i don't know where it can fit into gcp serverless proposal.

Comment: Also i saw that google is launching PubSub lite that imo seems very similar to kafka

Comment: Hmm, I don't know Kafka very well. IMO, PubSub lite is only for regional use and with a flat price (per provisioned capacity). At the opposite of PubSub (standard) which is global and a pay-per-message pricing.

Comment: If you need a long-running program, I recommend using Kubernetes with GKE, or GCE directly if you don't need Kubernetes-level complexity.

Comment: Ahmet's proposal should be the way to go if you need an instance to constantly pull kafka. The other solution would be considering whether kafka is the appropriate product in your scenario knowing that it's not push based.

Comment: @FabrizioTognetto Curious where you eventually landed for your system design. 1) Can you still use serverless ways (Cloud Run, App Engine) to host message producers of Kafka? 2) Did you have to use GKE/GCE to host Kafka consumer apps, or did you find a serverless way to host your consumer apps, as well? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @ric i initially wrote a Kafka to http connector, that installed on gke was listening on Kafka and redirect events to cloud run making an http request. But I finally ended up using pub/sub with push subscription on a http endpoint. Pub/sub now has a ordering feature and that was what I needed.

Comment: https://github.com/quantosapplications/kafka-consume-to-http-service This is the Kafka connector I wrote if you need. It was doing exactly what I needed but I’m not a gke expert so I decided to use only server less approach

Comment: Thank you, @FabrizioTognetto! That sums up the consumer side. On the producer side of Kafka, serverless worked out "out of the box". Correct?

Comment: Yes @ric producing an event often occur during a request from a user (eg. a user sign up using a POST request to the user service) so in that case the server is already woken up handling that request

Answer (score 0):

> Since cloud run is a serverless solutions that scale to zero, we cannot make it listen to kafka topic, because the service could shut down during the night because no request arrive.

You can avoid this easily by setting a minimum amount of CloudRun Services and allocate the CPU all the time.

Allocate the CPU all the time:

[image: Allocate CPU all the time]

Set a minimum number of active services (e.g. as many as your topic has partitions):

[image: min number of services]

Note that this way, your Cloud Run service produces costs all the time.

You can achieve the same with terraform:

```
 ....
    metadata {
      annotations = {
        ...
        "run.googleapis.com/cpu-throttling"       = false
        "autoscaling.knative.dev/minScale"        = 2
      }
    }
```